# Group by on same table not return most recent record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, codeigniter

I have records in appointment table with patient information.When i try to fetch latest patient appointment using group by it doesn't give me right result.I used group by with order by.Attached the table schema and query

[image]

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` where appointment.patient = 2650 group by appointment.patient 
order by appointment.id desc
```

Above query return record whose id is 6718

Note : In this query i have added where condition only for one patient and i want the all patient latest appointment.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand completely. If you are filtering the rows in the WHERE clause by the patient using this: appointment.patient = 2650 then can't you just select the max(whatever_your_date_column) for that particular patient since the WHERE clause limits the records to just that patient anyway? Why GROUP BY? Or are there different kinds of dates for a patient?

Comment: above is an example of one patient. I have thousands of records in table

Comment: if i add max(date) it will give me the date of the latest record and all other data of the old one

Comment: So do you just want the row with the max date vale per each patient or will it be just for one patient?

Comment: @J2112O for each patient

Answer (score 2):

It happened information provided in group by, Because mysql will club your appoitment records in non aggrigiate manner, you need to specify a tie braker like max(),min() fucntion to tell mysql which record you need to take after groupBy .

```
SELECT patient, MAX(date) as latest_date 
FROM appointment 
WHERE patient = 2650 
GROUP BY patient 
ORDER BY latest_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand correctly that you only need the last appointment number for each of the patients? If so, does it solve your question? If not, present the expected output, please.

```
select max(id) as last_appt, patient
from appointment
group by patient
order by patient;
```

Here's [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2225004f9c328ccd82027c7254ad07a5) example

Comment: You can't be sure that this will always return latest appointment. IDs don't have to be in direct correlation with dates. 

What if latest appointment has lower ID?

Comment: right, that's why I'm asking about expected output. In my case, I took ID instead of some date, coz it is presented in the original code block (order by clause). I think, that TS can change this column to the correct one, if needed

Comment: thanks, @Ben for your comment . In my query, i also compare the date

Comment: @Jesusbrother  your query does not give me the latest  row.it will return the oldest record with max id

Answer (score 0):

If you have Laravel models setup its as easy as this

```
Appointment::where('patient', 2650)->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

also I don't recommend ordering anything by Id, since you have add_date column I suggest using it like so `orderByDesc('add_date')`

Comment: this will give all records where patient is 2650